# Styling QTabWidget background with CSS

Tags: css, qt, qtabwidget

I wish to set a custom background color for active QTabWidget tab. Unfortunately, I can't figure out the desired selector.
On Linux the following hack works:

```
QTabWidget::tab > QWidget > QWidget {
        background: #fff;
}
```

But on Windows I have to use one more QWidget:

```
QTabWidget::tab > QWidget > QWidget > QWidget {
        background: #fff;
}
```

Is there a "real" solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use QTabBar and not QTabWidget. The selectors you should use are the following:

```
// Control the tab-bar with respect to the QTabWidget
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
        left: 5px;
}

// Control the look of the tab in general
QTabBar::tab {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

// Control the look of the tab when it is selected
QTabBar::tab:selected
{
        // Add css parameters
}
// Control the look of the tab when hovering over it
QTabBar::tab:hover 
{
        // Add css parameters
}

// Control the look of the tab when it is not selected
QTabBar::tab:!selected
{
        // Add css parameters
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I diagnosed the problem further. I insert a QScrollArea as a tab with the desired contents. If I ignore the scroll area your solution works. Setting background on the SA itself doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to change the background of the tab or the background of the widget that is displayed?

Comment: Preferably both - in case the scroll area isn't used.

Comment: `QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
scrollArea->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
scrollArea->setWidget(editorWidget);

mLeafWidget->addTab(scrollArea, tabLabel);`

Comment: You want to change the background color of scrollArea every time the user selects the tab?

Comment: Yes, I want the selected tab to have a white background, not the system grey.

Comment: By changing the background of the tab widget you are not changing the backgrounds of the widgets in it. The background of the scroll bar area and the editorWidget inside it are not affected by the background of the tab widget itself. Use the star operator to apply the same style on all children of a widget, eg `QTabWidget * {background: #fff}` . Check [CSS inheritance](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet-syntax.html#inheritance) for more details. You could also use a code-based solution instead of changing the stylesheet.

Comment: Using `QTabWidget *` gives wrong results - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/193/zrzutekranu1uv.png/ Also it overwrites every specialized css for every widget.

Comment: Well the problem is `QTabWidget QScrollArea` doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Can you try this one? `   QTabWidget QFrame[isScrollArea="true"] { background-color: #fff; }`

Comment: I reproduce this. Seems like a bug in Windows